# consult with group by in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

what I am looking for is that to my table that I have, I can make a grouping according to some conditions that I implement

[image]

I have this table, which I am calling as follows:

Codigo.gs

```
function pendiente_inci(){

 var hojaCalculo = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1XkGF_rmsuOM_iFFKWI1-TTu6GMdHTsdjhasf");
 var hojaDatos = hojaCalculo.getSheetByName('Data');
 var numColumns = hojaDatos.getLastColumn();
 var ultimaFila = hojaDatos.getLastRow();

  var row = hojaDatos.getRange(1, 1, ultimaFila, numColumns).getValues();

  return row.lenght;
 }
```

Here I am calling all my table shown in the image, but what I want to call is the amount of "pending" that I have of the workers. what making a query a database would be like this:

```
 select usuario,count(*) from Data where estado="pendiente" group by usuario
```

How could I do to make this query in my code.gs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through the data returned by your [`.getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) call. Note that it returns a two-dimensional array of values.

```
  var valores = hojaDatos.getRange(1, 1, ultimaFila, numColumns).getValues();
  var usuarios = {}; // This will contain the results
  for (var i = 1; i < valores.length; i++) { // Skip the header row by starting with i = 1
    var row = valores[i]; // This is the entire row
    var estado = row[2]; // Assuming "estado" is in column C. This is equivalent to writing valores[i][2].
    if (estado == "pendiente") {
      var nombre = row[1]; // Assuming "usuario" is in column B. This is equivalent to writing valores[i][1].

      // If the user does not exist in the users object, add them. Set the count of jobs to zero.
      if (!usuarios.hasOwnProperty(nombre)) {
        usuarios[nombre] = { trabajos: 0 };
      }

      // Increment the user's job count
      usuarios[nombre].trabajos++;
    }
  }
```

Once you've gone through the data and calculated what you want with it, you can do anything else. It's not clear to me what your objective is from the code that you posted, but at minimum, you could [Logger.log()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#log(Object)) it.

```
function pendiente_inci() {
  var hojaCalculo = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1XkGF_rmsuOM_iFFKWI1-TTu6GMdHTsdjhasf");
  var hojaDatos = hojaCalculo.getSheetByName('Data');
  var numColumns = hojaDatos.getLastColumn();
  var ultimaFila = hojaDatos.getLastRow();

  var valores = hojaDatos.getRange(1, 1, ultimaFila, numColumns).getValues();
  var usuarios = {}; // This will contain the results
  for (var i = 1; i < valores.length; i++) { // Skip the header row by starting with i = 1
    var row = valores[i]; // This is the entire row
    var estado = row[2]; // Assuming "estado" is in column C. This is equivalent to writing valores[i][2].
    if (estado == "pendiente") {
      var nombre = row[1]; // Assuming "usuario" is in column B. This is equivalent to writing valores[i][1].

      // If the user does not exist in the users object, add them. Set the count of jobs to zero.
      if (!usuarios.hasOwnProperty(nombre)) {
        usuarios[nombre] = { trabajos: 0 };
      }

      // Increment the user's job count
      usuarios[nombre].trabajos++;
    }
  }

  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(usuarios));
}
```